# SwiftUI: Refresh child view when parent was updated by other child

Tags: swift, swiftui, dataflow

I have two tab views and their parent view. When child1 updates the content in my parent view, I want the second child to be refreshed, which does not seem to work. Here my parent view code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

   @StateObject var collectionContainer = CollectionContainer()
   @State private var trashIndex = -1

   @State var items: [CustomItem] = []
   @State var item: CustomItem = CustomItem(name: "", amount: -1)

   var trashProxy: Binding<ContentWrapper> {
       Binding<ContentWrapper>(
           get: {
               return self.collectionContainer.getTrash()
           },
           set: {
               self.collectionContainer.collections[trashIndex] = $0
               self.items = [$0.content[0]]
               self.item = $0.content[0]
           })
   }

   var body: some View {
       TabView {
           ExistingItemsView(collectionContainer: collectionContainer, trashWrapper: trashProxy)
           .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
           .tabItem {
               Image(systemName: "tray")
               Text("Items")
           }
        
           RemovedItemsView(items: self.items, item: self.item)
           .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
           .tabItem {
               Image(systemName: "trash")
               Text("Trash")
           }
       }
       .accentColor(.green)
       .onAppear {
           self.trashIndex = self.collectionContainer.getTrashIndex()
       }
   }
}
```

In my understanding, the setter of `trashProxy` (which is called after child1 aka `ExistingItemView` changes `collectionContainer`; confirmed by debugging) updates the State of `ContentView` and thus triggers a refresh. This should also refresh `RemovedItemsView` which should then display `items` and `item` in their updated state. Unfortunatly, this is not the case, only after an @State update in `RemovedItemsView` by switching the segmented control the updated values appear.

Here is my  `RemovedItemsView` code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RemovedItemsView: View {
    
    @State private var displayStyle = 0
    let styles = ["Detailed", "Total"]
    
    @State private var dummy = "" 
    
    let items: [CustomItem]
    let item: CustomItem
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker(selection: $displayStyle, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0..<styles.count) { index in
                        Text(self.styles[index]).tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(.trailing, 90)
                .padding(.leading, 90)
                
                if(displayStyle == 0)
                {
                    SegViewOne(items: items)
                }
                else if (displayStyle == 1)
                {
                    SegViewTwo(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SegViewOne : View {
    
    let items: [CustomItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.0) { i, item in
                Text("\(item.name): \(item.amount)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SegViewTwo : View {
    
    let item: CustomItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            if(item.amount > 0 )
            {
                Text("\(item.name): \(item.amount)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @State is meant to be private to structs, if you want to update “RemovedItemsView", I believe you need to pass items as binding, just as you did in “ExistingItemsView" .

Comment: I tried it, now instead of `RemovedItemsView(items: self.items, item: self.item` I have `RemovedItemsView(items: self.$items, item: self.$item)` and in `RemovedItemsView` instead of `let items: [CustomItem]   let item: CustomItem`I have `@Binding var items: [CustomItem]  @Binding var item: CustomItem`. Still no behavior change.. :/

Comment: is customItem defined as struct or a class? it’s always good to use regular types like Int, bool, strings with @State, and for custom types one should use class, when data needs to passed to child class.

Comment: Its defined as a class

Comment: @State are meant to work with structs value types, and not classes that are referenced types.

Comment: So what does that mean for my implementation, how can I get it to work? I'm pretty new to all this declarative programming

Comment: You need to use classes with “ObservableObject” protocol. You can read 100 days of swiftUI by Paul Hudson, it will help you master all  the basic concepts.Here is the link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui.

Comment: Thanks, playing around with @ObservableObject led me to a solution :)